Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.twiliovoicereactnative.JSEventEmitter.setContext(com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext)
Trying to integrate Twilio voice official sdk, I have completed all the steps as per android but still getting the following error after the app is successfully built.
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.twiliovoicereactnative.JSEventEmitter.setContext(com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext) on a null object reference
The official package url https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice-react-native/tree/main
I'm pasting below the MainApplication.kt, MainActivity.kt, MainReactNativeHost.kt
MainApplication.KT
import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage
import com.intercom.reactnative.IntercomModule
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader
import com.twiliovoicereactnative.VoiceApplicationProxy;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Build
import android.content.Context

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost =
    object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
      override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> =
          PackageList(this).packages.apply {

          }

      override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"

      override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

      override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
      override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
    }

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  private val mReactNativeHost = MainReactNativeHost(this)
  private val voiceApplicationProxy = VoiceApplicationProxy(mReactNativeHost)


  override fun registerReceiver(receiver: BroadcastReceiver?, filter: IntentFilter): Intent? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
        super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
    } else {
        super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
 
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
  }

  override fun onTerminate() {
    voiceApplicationProxy.onTerminate()
    super.onTerminate()
  }

}

MainActivity.KT
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Build
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.twiliovoicereactnative.VoiceActivityProxy;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {




  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "appName"





    private val activityProxy = VoiceActivityProxy(this) { permission ->
        when {
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO == permission -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Microphone permissions needed. Please allow in your application settings.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT == permission -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Bluetooth permissions needed. Please allow in your application settings.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2 && Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS == permission -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Notification permissions needed. Please allow in your application settings.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }



  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    SplashScreen.show(this)
      super.onCreate(null)
        activityProxy.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
        }
        window.addFlags(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
        )
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    activityProxy.onDestroy()
    super.onDestroy()
  }

  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent)
      activityProxy.onNewIntent(intent)
  }


}

MainReactNativeHost.kt
import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.twiliovoicereactnative.VoiceApplicationProxy

class MainReactNativeHost(application: Application) : VoiceApplicationProxy.VoiceReactNativeHost(application) {
    override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

    override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> {
        val packages = PackageList(this).packages
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here
        // packages.add(MyReactNativePackage())
        return packages
    }

    override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"
}


